# Why the code avoids storing these points

Tags: numerical-methods, programming

I have a very simple Euler's integration method. The author avoids storing specific points. I need to know why. This is Fortran 77 code but readable. I don't know the benefit of the variable S in the following code.

```
PROGRAM main

IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H)
IMPLICIT REAL*8(O-Z)
OPEN(1,STATUS='UNKNOWN',FILE='DATFIL');
W=2.
T=0.
S=0.
X=0.
XD=W
H=.01
DO WHILE(T <= 10.)
    S=S+H
    XDD=-W*W*X
    XD=XD+H*XDD
    X=X+H*XD
    T=T+H
    IF(S>=.09999)THEN
        S=0.
        XTHEORY=SIN(W*T)
        WRITE(9,*)T,X,XTHEORY
        WRITE(1,*)T,X,XTHEORY
    ENDIF       
END DO  

END PROGRAM main
```

Comment: Note that this is the semi-implicit or symplectic Euler method as $x_{k+1}$ is computed using $v_{k+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`S` is only being used to produce output, via `WRITE`, every ten steps.  Since all the output is written to units `1` (`DATFIL`) and `9` (unless your environment defines this unit, I'm used to this defaulting to the file `fort.9`), there is no reason to store the points.

You could of course, store the points in an array instead of, or in addition to, writing them to the file(s).

---

If you want to see every step in your file, replace this block

```
    IF(S>=.09999)THEN
        S=0.
        XTHEORY=SIN(W*T)
        WRITE(9,*)T,X,XTHEORY
        WRITE(1,*)T,X,XTHEORY
    ENDIF
```

with this one

```
    XTHEORY=SIN(W*T)
    WRITE(9,*)T,X,XTHEORY
    WRITE(1,*)T,X,XTHEORY
```

You are free to also remove `S=0.` and `S=S+H`, as they are no longer needed.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for getting data every ten steps? I'm asking this because with other experiments in the book, ignoring this step produces weird results.

Comment: I would imagine it is to avoid getting $1000$ lines of output, when $100$ will demonstrate the method.  Adding a little to my answer...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you think this "avoids storing specific points": no points are stored at all.  The code is solving the differential equation $x''(t) = -w^2 x(t)$ for $0 \le t \le 10$ with step size $h = 0.01$.  The S is just there so that results will be printed (along with the "theory" values $\sin(w t)$) at $t$ intervals of $0.1$, thus every $10$ steps.

Comment: by storing I meant written to the file. Is there any benefit of printing data to the file every 10 steps rather than printing all data to the file?

Comment: A person reading the file might find $1000$ lines of data a bit overwhelming; $100$ lines might be more convenient.